# Unable to create docker checkpoint in docker experimental

Tags: docker

After enabling docker experimental, I am trying to move running container to another host through docker checkpoint command. First I am trying to create checkpoint with following command:

```
 docker checkpoint create 52922ace26fa cp
```

But it fails with following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot checkpoint container 52922ace26fa: rpc error: code = 2 desc = exit status 1: "Unable to execute CRIU command: criu\n"
```

I have tried it both in ubuntu and centos, 
Here is docker version:

```
Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:06:25 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Is there any solution or workaround for this?
And as it is experimental feature , is there any way to move container's at runtime ?

Comment: Did you install CRIU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRIU is an external dependency for this feature and wont work without it. Execute below commands and install it

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:criu/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y criu
```

Once installed then try the checkpointing again

For more details refer to

https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/v1.13.0-rc4/experimental/checkpoint-restore.md

Comment: Tarun, apt-get update gives such errors:
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages

Is there any other way to install CRIU (I've tried from build from sources but in vain)?
Is  apt-get criu the same?

Thanks.

Comment: Try Ubuntu 14.04 instead of 16.04 for now and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

It seems like CRIU is not properly installed in your system. Could you please verify?

If otherwise, you can install(command):

```
sudo apt-get install criu
```

It is also possible to build CRIU from the source code. CRIU is written in C, So install standard `gcc` and `make` packages to be able to create the binary. Clone the CRIU github repos:

```
https://github.com/checkpoint-restore/criu
```

A further instruction on How to build is given here(Official page of CRIU)

https://criu.org/Installation